# A remark about the map $\partial^*:H^{*}(A;V)\to H^{*+1}(X,A)$ of the l.e.S. in cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

My question is about a remark from lecture about the connecting-homomorphism of the long exact sequence in homology of a pair $(X,A)$.

Let $(X,A)$ a pair of topological spaces, $V$ be an abelian group and consider the long exact sequence in singular cohomology

$$..H^{n-1}(A;V)\xrightarrow{\partial^{n-1}}H^n(X,A)\to H^n(X;V)\to H^n(A;V)\xrightarrow{\partial^{n}}...$$
Let $\partial^*:H^{*}(A;V)\to H^{*+1}(X,A)$ be the connecting homomorphism in the sequence above.

In lecture we had the remark: The map $\partial^*:H^{*}(A;V)\to H^{*+1}(X,A)$ can be described as follows: Let $\alpha:C_n(A;\mathbb{Z})\to V$ be a cocycle. Extend $\alpha$ on $C_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ by $\hat{\alpha}(\sigma )=0$ for $\sigma \in C_n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ with $\operatorname{im}(\sigma)\nsubseteq A$. Then we have: $$\partial^n [\alpha]=[d^n(\hat{\alpha})]=[\hat{\alpha} \circ d_{n+1}]\in H^{n+1}(X,A).$$

I don't understand this remark, in my opion there must be a mistake. Because if $d^n$ in the expression $[d^n(\hat{\alpha})]$ is the boundary map $d^n:C^{n}(X;V)\to C^{n+1}(X;V)$, then $[\hat{\alpha} \circ d_{n+1}]$ is not in $ H^{n+1}(X,A)$. If $d^n$ in the expression $[d^n(\hat{\alpha})]$ is the boundary map $d^n:C^{n}(X,A;V)\to C^{n+1}(X,A;V)$, $[d^n(\hat{\alpha})]$ is zero.

Where is the mistake? Is there a mistake on my thoughts or is the remark wrong? If the remark is wrong, what should be the correct version?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, since $\alpha$ is a cocycle, that $\alpha \circ d^A_n = 0$. However, you do not know that $\hat\alpha \circ d^X_n = 0$! So $\hat\alpha$ is not even a cocycle. What you know is that, if $i_* : C_*(A) \to C_*(X)$ is the inclusion, then
$$\hat\alpha \circ d^X_n \circ i_{n+1} = \hat\alpha \circ i_n \circ d^A_n = \alpha \circ d^A_n = 0,$$
and so by definition of $C^{n+1}(X,A;V)$, it follows that $\hat\alpha \circ d^X_n \in C^{n+1}(X;V)$ is in fact in $C^{n+1}(X,A;V)$, i.e. it vanishes on $C_{n+1}(A)$, and it is a cocycle.

But it is not a coboundary in $C^*(X,A;V)$, because it would need to be the codifferential of something in $C^n(X,A;V)$; but $\hat\alpha$ does not vanish (in general) on $C_n(A)$, so in general $\hat\alpha$ is in $C^n(X;V)$ but not in $C^n(X,A;V)$. So you cannot conclude from this that $\hat\alpha \circ d^X_n$ is in the image of
$$\delta^n : C^n(X,A;V) \to C^{n+1}(X,A;V),$$
i.e. you cannot conclude that $\hat\alpha \circ d_n^X$ is a coboundary in $C^*(X,A;V)$. The remark is correct.

---

PS: This is a general construction known as the [snake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma), applied to:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> C^n(X,A) @>>> C^n(X) @>>> C^n(A) @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> C^{n+1}(X,A) @>>> C^{n+1}(X) @>>> C^{n+1}(A) @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$
The snake lemma is a very powerful tool in homological algebra.

Comment: ah, ok!! Thanks for the explanation!